# Monotonicity of solutions of IVP

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f, g: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions and locally Lipschitz for every point $(t, x) \in U$. Suppose that $g(t, x) > f(t, x)$ for all $(t, x) \in U$.
Let $(t_0, x_0) \in U$ and $t_1 > t_0$.
Prove that if  $\psi:[t_0, t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of $x' = g(t, x)$ with $x(t_0) = x_0$, and $\varphi:[t_0, t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of the equation $x' = f(t, x)$ with $x(t_0) = x_0$, then $\psi(t) \geq \varphi(t)$ for all $t \in [t_0, t_1]$.
Prove that the same holds in an analogous way if $g(t, x) \geq f(t, x)$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the easy part.

Let $\delta(t) = \psi(t)-\phi(t)$. Since $\dot{\delta}(t_0)>0$, we know there is a small interval $(0,\delta) $ where $\delta(t)>0$.

Let $Z= \{ t \in (t_0,t_1] \mid \delta(t) = 0 \}$. I claim that $Z$ is empty. Suppose not, and let $T= \inf Z$ (we know $T \ge \delta >0$). Since $\dot{\delta}(T)>0$, we must have $\delta(t)<0$ for $t \in (T-\eta, T]$ for some $\eta>0$, and using the intermediate value theorem we get a contradiction to the definition of $T$. In particular, $\psi(t)>\phi(t) $ for $t\in (t_0,t_1]$.

For the second part, suppose that $\delta(t^*)<0$ for some $t^* \in (t_0,t_1]$ and let $t_z \in [t_0,t^*)$ such that $\delta(t_z) = 0$ and $\delta(s) <0$ for $s \in (t_z,t^*]$. Then, for $t \in (t_z,t^*]$ we have
$-\dot{\delta}(t) = f(t, \phi(t)) - g(t,\psi(t)) \le g(t, \phi(t)) - g(t,\psi(t)) \le L |\phi(t) - \psi(t)| = L (-\delta(t))$ and so
$-\delta(t) \le (-\delta(t_z))e^{L(t-t_z)} = 0$, which is a contradiction, hence $\delta(t) \ge 0$ for $t \in [t_0,t_1]$.

Note that the first part follows from the second, but I think it is useful to establish that the inequality is strict (mostly) in the first case.

Another approach to the second part, given the first, would be to consider the system $g_\epsilon(t,x) = g(t,x)+\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon>0$, then the solutions $\psi_\epsilon$ satisfy the inequality $\psi_\epsilon(t) \ge \phi(t)$ and taking limits yields the desired result. However, while cute, this approach requires establishing continuity of solutions to small perturbations (well posedness).